# How to trigger EventMap event for template from another template's event in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I stumbled across a really funky requirement in Meteor.js — I have 2 buttons ("submit as child" and "submit as sibling") and text input that reacts to pressed keys. Buttons work on their own, but I'd like to trigger "click" event made with Template.my_template.events(...) from the input's keydown event.

I managed to script everything using following construct (coffeescript) of using both EventMap and rendered() callback:

```
Template.my_template.events = 

    'keydown input': () -> reactToPressedKey();

Template.my_template.rendered = () ->

    $('click .submit_child').bind 'click', () -> doStuff();
    $('click .submit_sibling').bind 'click', () -> doStuff();
```

It works like I expected, but I wonder if there's any better solution like using only EventMap (Template.my_template.events)?

Comment: Your current setup is probably easier to read than having one event map reference another event map

Answer (score -1):

Just put the events in the other template.

```
Template.other_template.events 
  'click .submit_child': doStuff
  'click .submit_sibling': doStuff

Template.my_template.events
  'keydown input': reactToPressedKey
```