# How in Meteor can we call from a template's event code the event code of another template?

Tags: meteor

So, ho can we trigger a template's event from the event of another template?

A similar question was answered IMPOV unclearly for my need, but Staskoverflow says to avoid asking for clarifications.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518761/how-to-trigger-eventmap-event-for-template-from-another-templates-event-in-mete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

An underlying function

```
Template.foo.events({
    'click .foo': function(e,t) {
        doStuff();
    }    
})

Template.bar.events({
    'click .bar': function(e,t) {
        doStuff();
    }    
})
```

An event trigger

```
Template.bar.events({
  'click .bar': function(e,t) {
    $('.foo').trigger('click');
  }
})
```

I think the first is more robust, but either works.